# How to stop a fixed background attachment image at certain part of scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code for an attached background image. I would like to stop it at a certain part of the screen on scroll. How can I achieve this?

Here is an example.. Would like to stop the icon that looks like its falling right above the optin form
https://www.loom.com/share/33bc067a7c64469c99129728ec7ecc2a

```
.form-image-scroll {
    background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dqwzka5cv/image/upload/v1586108678/Tequilas/Website/tacoguy-min.png) no-repeat top 25% right 42% fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opportunity to use `position:sticky`.

`position:sticky` is positioned based on your scroll position, but it also stays within its container element. You're going to want to implement this like the "doctor" on [Alligator.io](https://alligator.io/css/position-sticky/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-image-scroll"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.form-image-scroll {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dqwzka5cv/image/upload/v1586108678/Tequilas/Website/tacoguy-min.png) no-repeat top 25% right 42% fixed;
}
```

You may need some additional CSS to properly position it with your other elements and to get the image to properly display, but this will move the element into view during scroll and stop it at the bottom of the container div.

Comment: Thanks for that. Using WordPress and a theme builder so think something may be off a little or doing it wrong..

Made a short video here.
https://www.loom.com/share/05b3e661844a4ea8a447f931cd666d91

https://tequilamex.com/home-2/

Comment: Interesting I tried that link but can't get the elements to move when copying the exact CSS and HTML they used..
https://tequilamex.com/test-dynamic-hours/

Comment: Unfortunately, "overflow: hidden;" breaks sticky because the browser isn't sure where elements start and stop.
Also unfortunately, templates love to spam "overflow:hidden" all over the place. That page has it on several parent elements.